# How to install ffmpeg on CentOS 6

Tags: ffmpeg, terminal, centos6

I have been trying to install ffmpeg for 2 days now and had no luck. I have tried countless videos on youtube, step by steps on google with no luck. Any help would be great.

I have a Centos 6 server.
Yes I am using root ssh in terminal on mac.
Commands I tried are:

1. `wget http://mirror.ffmpeginstaller.com/old/scripts/ffmpeg8/ffmpeginstaller.8.0. tar.gz`
2. `tar -xvzf ffmpeginstaller.8.0.tar.gz`
3. `cd ffmpeginstaller.8.0`
4. `./install.sh`

Comment: You're trying to install an old version of ffmpeg? FWIW looks like you can get a package on nux: https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-centos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Static build

Easiest method is to download a recent version that is already compiled.

1. Download a static build of `ffmpeg` from https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/
2. Extract the archive file you just downloaded from the above site
3. (optional) Copy or move the `ffmpeg` file into `/usr/local/bin`

## Compile

If you prefer to make a custom build you can compile. See [FFmpeg Wiki: Compile FFmpeg on CentOS](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos).

Comment: I DID IT !. I had to download the release 3.4.1 version due to my system requirements but after spending the night on it i managed to do it. Thanks for all the help i really appreciate it, @LordNeckbeard